# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory after adding second database connection to Symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, database-connection, multiple-databases

I have a Symfony2 app that has had a single database connection.

I added a second database connection to the configs and I started getting this error for both database connections:

```
[PDOException]                                    
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

After googling, I found that for that error I need to change my *db_host* from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`.

Why is this an issue when, with one database connection, `localhost` worked fine?

Also, is there a way to get around having to change my *db_host* in my configs and leave them as `localhost`?

**Update:**

Here is my config file:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection:    default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   "pdo_mysql"
                host:     "localhost"
                port:     null
                dbname:   "db_name"
                user:     "db_user"
                password: "db_pass"
                charset:  UTF8
            d7:
                driver:   "pdo_mysql"
                host:     "localhost"
                port:     null
                dbname:   "db_name2"
                user:     "db_user"
                password: "db_pass"
                charset:  UTF8


    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
            d7:
                connection: d7
```

Comment: Shouldn't matter... in your `hosts` file, localhost should map to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: You may want to paste your full configs for the db connections (sans usernames and passwords, of course).

Comment: @LynnCrumbling I know it shouldn't matter, but it apparently does :-)